# $items[$k]->$args['output_key'] = $i++; - error PHP 7

Tags: php7

Hemos migrado de php 5 a 7 y no hemos tenido precaución de hacer la prueba previa.... (error por nuestra parte) y al ejecutar la web aparecen estos mensajes

> **Notice**: Indirect modification of overloaded property WP_Post::$Array has no effect in /var/www/vhost/nironet.es/home/html/wp-includes/nav-menu.php on line 604
>
> **Warning**: Illegal string offset 'output_key' in /var/www/vhost/nironet.es/home/html/wp-includes/nav-menu.php on line 604 
>   y en esa línea esto es lo que hay 
>       $items[$k]->$args['output_key'] = $i++; 
>   y la verdad es que no tengo por donde cogerlo.... alguna sugerencia?
>   Muchas gracias
>   Nico

Comment: Este error generalmente ocurre cuando usted no empieza la variable y intenta a la utilizar como objecto

Comment: Si dejas parte del código donde se genera el problema, es más posible que alguien pueda ayudarte..

Comment: este es la parte de código para ver si ayuda
if ( ARRAY_A == $args['output'] ) {
  $GLOBALS['_menu_item_sort_prop'] = $args['output_key'];
  usort($items, '_sort_nav_menu_items');
  $i = 1;
  foreach( $items as $k => $item ) {
   $items[$k]->$args['output_key'] = $i++;
  }
 }

Answer (score 0):

parta mejor entendimiento y claridad , pego mas código a ver si se puede ver el error
$items = array_map( 'wp_setup_nav_menu_item', $items );

```
if ( ! is_admin() ) // Remove invalid items only in frontend
    $items = array_filter( $items, '_is_valid_nav_menu_item' );

if ( ARRAY_A == $args['output'] ) {
    $GLOBALS['_menu_item_sort_prop'] = $args['output_key'];
    usort($items, '_sort_nav_menu_items');
    $i = 1;
    foreach( $items as $k => $item ) {
        $items[$k]->$args['output_key'] = $i++;
    }
}
```